# Can I assign two functions to a single menu item in Google sheet app script?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

Is it possible to assign two function names into a single custom menu item like this script:

```
function onOpen() {

    var menuItems = [
    {name: 'Draw Borders', functionName: 'borders'},
    {name: 'Draw Borders_1stFloor', functionName: 'borders1stFloor'},
    {name: 'Draw Borders_2ndFloor', functionName: 'borders2ndFloor'}
]; SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().addMenu('Weekened_Functions', menuItems);
```

I would like to keep one menu item 'Draw Borders' and associate with it the three functions `('borders'+'borders2ndFloor'+'borders1stFloor')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: It's not possible.

Instead, from the menu item call a function that calls the functions that you want to be executed. Example:

```
function main(){
  borders();
  borders2ndFloor();
  borders1stFloor();
}
```